# how to pass parameter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have written a method for user authentication method in REST web service. After successful authentication, I want to pass the username. How can I pass it? Can I get value pass from login web service method in other web service method.

My code for login is:

```
@GET

@Produces("application/json")
public Response login(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@Context HttpServletResponse res,@QueryParam("loginname")String loginname,@QueryParam("password")String password) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    userDAOImpl impl = new userDAOImpl();
    Mongo mongo=impl.getConnection("127.0.0.1","27017");
    DB db=impl.getDataBase(mongo,"userdb");
    DBCollection coll=impl.getColl(db,"userdb");
    userDTO dto = new userDTO();
    dto.setUsername(loginname);
    dto.setPassword(password);
    if(impl.checkUser(coll, dto))
    {
        mongo.close();


        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    else
    {
       return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: please always tag your questions with the programming language you are using, or a more specific tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if you are using some sort of web framework here or not, so I'll answer the question as if you aren't.

Servlets do allow you to add attributes to a request (which are gone after the request is processed), to a page (again, lost when the page is gone), or session (which lives as long as your browser/servlet maintain the session).

I'd suggest you start here with a [simple example of how to deal with servlet attributes and paramters](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/State.html).  And [here's a more detailed explaination](http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/intro_to_servlets.html).

Comment: hi jay, the question i want to ask is who to pass parameter from REST web service or to REST web service? Maybe what you mean is I can behave servlet as a web service. But here I mean is Pure POJO class which create as a REST web service. thanks